# Why can't I create nodes on EC2 default network with OpsCenter 5.2.1?

Tags: amazon-vpc, cassandra, opscenter, datastax-enterprise

I've had to update our DataStax OpsCenter service from **5.1.3** to **5.2.1** because when I tried to add a new node to our Cassandra Cluster (**DSE 4.6.6** on Amazon EC2) it said that *"No nodes were available to retrieve a configuration from."*

Updating to 5.2.1 fixed that issue, but it created a new one; now the VPC ID doesn't allow me to create nodes on the EC2 default network, it's not shown entirely, it only allows me to choose one of the 2 VPC's we already have.

It seems that they've added VPC support on 5.2.0...

> Support for AWS VPC when creating clusters/nodes in the EC2 Cloud.
>   (OPSC-3429)
>   http://docs.datastax.com/en/opscenter/5.2/opsc/release_notes/opscReleaseNotes520.html

It shouldn't be mandatory, since on the previous versions we had to create our cluster without a VPC, but the "Add node" documentation is not promising...

> A list of current VPC IDs in the region in which the current OpsCenter instance is built. Both the VPC ID and the network range are displayed. The AWS default VPC ID is also indicated. The VPC ID list is prepopulated after entering your EC2 credentials. An AWS VPC (Amazon Web Services Virtual Private Cloud) holds one contiguous network range that can be subdivided into subnets. 
>   http://docs.datastax.com/en/opscenter/5.2//opsc/online_help/opscAddNodeCloudCluster.html

I need to create nodes on the default EC2 network, since the other nodes are already there and migrating to VPC is not an option for us right now (perhaps in a not-so-near future we'll have time to do so).

- Is this a bug on OpsCenter 5.2.1?
- Something that I need to update on our settings?
- Is there a workaround to create the server in the old-way? (ie, downgrade and fix the configuration node error somehow)

Answer (score 0):

This is a duplicate of a StackOverflow post which has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32704753/why-opscenter-doesnt-allow-me-create-nodes-on-the-default-ec2-network-anymore